# How to solve strange characters in SQL Management Studio 18

Tags: sql-server

Can anybody help here?
I'm importing a txt file to a table, using flat file import on MSSMS 18.

But the imported data apears with ascii table characters like on picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He1wy.png)

Don't know how to solve this.

Comment: That's the UNICODE replacement character.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29.  It's used to represent invalid or unknown characters.  The best way I know of to find it or get rid of it in SQL is to check for it using a binary collation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been checking database properties and Collation is already Latin1_General_CI_AS, the correct one for my region.

Comment: Change the datatype of column4 to NVARCHAR and try the import again.

Comment: doesn't solve the problem, nor even changing all columns to NVARCHAR

Comment: I could be the encoding of the file. Otherwise, I think the next step for this question is to add few example lines of the import file and the schema for the table.

Comment: Have you examined the txt file content in something like notepad++, what are the characters that are not being displayed?

Comment: Seems like it's breaking the ó (U+00F3) characters. Is the source file UTF-8 encoded? The Import Flat File wizard was something added to SSMS around SQL Server 2017 with the intention of "simplifying" the import experience. One of the consequences of that simplification is that it doesn't let you choose the encoding of the source file. If you need to work with cp1252 (or other-than-UTF-8 encoded) files try using the old Import Data Wizard instead.

Comment: Problem solved. The cause was a txt source file encoded in ANSI, just copied the content to a new file encoded in utf-8. Thank you all for your help and interest.